# Enterprise Architect 13.5: How to change text color for operation(s)

Tags: enterprise-architect

Seems like a trival question but I'm stuck finding out how to change to text color for an operation(method) in Enterprise Architect 13.5.

The class name text color I can change through "Default Appearance" via Right mouse button. But I can NOT find a way to change the text color of one or more operation(s).

The reason I want this is because my class/object background color is dark(er) so I want a Light(er) text color for both my class name and operations so that they still are readable.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the color of individual operations.

You can only change the general default color using the general preferences.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer: It helped me out!